# Can I assign a function into a variable?

Tags: python

I was doing some experimenting while going through Coursera courses on functions and variables.

```
def x():
  print(20)
y = x
y()
print(y())
```

The results I got back were:

```
20
20
None
```

Why is there an extra None being printed? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: That None has nothing to do with assigning functions to variables. You would have seen the same effect if you did `print(x())` and removed `y` from your code entirely.

Comment: Simply put, because your function returns `None` and you print the result of calling your function.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the return value of x is None.
If you omit `return`  at the end of function definition, the function returns None. And `print` at the bottom prints the value returned from x.